# Filter characters with function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

What is the simplest way to substring character that already appear on the line ?

Is that possible to do this with function (means no VBA) ?

More information :

If I have cells like

```
   *A* *B* *C* *D* *E* *F*
  |        DATA           |  RESULT    |
1 | A | B | C |   | E | F |       D
2 | C |   |   |   | E | F |       ABD
```

Is there a function that can give this result :

`fx("ABCEF", "ABCDEF")`  returns `D`
`fx("CF", "ABCDEF")` returns `ABDE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt the `simplest way` (or at least not the shortest), but certainly possible without VBA:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH("A",A2:F2,0)),"A","")&IF(ISERROR(MATCH("B",A2:F2,0)),"B","")&IF(ISERROR(MATCH("c",A2:F2,0)),"C","")&IF(ISERROR(MATCH("D",A2:F2,0)),"D","")&IF(ISERROR(MATCH("E",A2:F2,0)),"E","")&IF(ISERROR(MATCH("F",A2:F2,0)),"F","")
```

Comment: `simpliest` sound cute... but good spelling is `simplest` :o) The function was missing in my formula was `ISERROR()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this small **UDF**:

```
Public Function WhatsLeft(LittleString As String, BigString As String) As String
    WhatsLeft = BigString
    For i = 1 To Len(LittleString)
        c = Mid(LittleString, i, 1)
        WhatsLeft = Replace(WhatsLeft, c, "")
    Next i
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that a complex formula acting as an array may be able to do this - but on a coding site, I'd keep it simple and run a VBA UDF

```
Sub Test()
Debug.Print Updated("ABCEF", "ABCDEF")
Debug.Print Updated("CF", "ABCDEF")
End Sub
```

*function*

```
Function Updated(strRep As String, strIn As String)
Dim objRegex As Object
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With objRegex
.Pattern = "[" & strRep & "]"
.Global = True
Updated = .Replace(strIn, vbNullString)
End With
End Function
```